# firefox startScroll and sendAsyncMessage

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, autoscroll, firefox-addon-restartless

In recent version of Firefox 31+ the startScroll(e) function was changed and should be called with startScroll(scrolldir, screenX, screenY)

Diff of the change:
https://hg.mozilla.org/integration/mozilla-inbound/diff/cc298e4b0f47/toolkit/content/widgets/browser.xml

Before the change I could initiate startScroll manually from my classic bootstrap.js extension with:

```
aWindow.gBrowser.selectedBrowser.startScroll(e);
```

I've received a tip on mozilla IRC channel to use [sendAsyncMessage "Autoscroll:Start"](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/content/browser-content.js#119) so I tried various combinations of

```
aWindow.gBrowser.selectedBrowser.startScroll("NSEW", e.screenX, e.screenY);
aWindow.gBrowser.selectedBrowser.messageManager.sendAsyncMessage("Autoscroll:Start", {scrolldir:"NSEW", screenX:e.screenX, screenY:e.screenY});
```

but nothing works.

Bare minimum boostrap.js extension of my problem can be seen on http://pastebin.com/azv1jePt

Does anybody have any idea how to manually start autoscroll in the newer version of Firefox directly from bootstrap.js extension, without using any *chrome* scripts?

Thanks
Senicar

Comment: This ones a stumper man i couldnt fugure it out :(

Comment: Interesting find though: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/content/widgets/browser.xml#948

Comment: @Noitidart thanks for looking into it, I guess I'll have to try my luck again on mozilla irc channels, because I can't figure it out too.

Comment: Tricky. Were either of you able to figure this one out?

Comment: @senicar did you figure this one out? another person on irc was having similar issue

Comment: @Noitidart sadly not yet, been pretty busy lately with work and haven't been able to muster up enough time to dive into the source.

Comment: Thanks for the update please share when you figure it out I am also very interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to simulate a middle button mousedown event from a frame script (no need to call startScroll nor sendAsyncMessage):

```
content.document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(new content.MouseEvent("mousedown", {
    view: content,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    button: 1,
    screenX: /* anEvent.screenX */,
    screenY: /* anEvent.screenY */
}));
```

Hope this helps